# Latex - multiple authors

Tags: texmaker

I am working with Latex and Texmaker to write a diploma thesis. 
Due to the fact, that every page is written by another author, I need to specify this author in the footer.

How does that work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us (a) which TeX distribution and which document class you use and (b) whether you use a package such as `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you can have a different author for every *page* in a diploma thesis, but that's beside the point. Here is one possible solution.

You could define some command that contains the name of the current author and include this in the footer definition (e.g., using `fancyhdr`). If you then renew that command wherever the author changes, the footer should change accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\currentauthor}{Ernest Rutherford}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\lfoot{Author: \currentauthor}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\Blindtext[8]
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\currentauthor}{Niels Bohr}
\Blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that if the value of `\currentauthor` changes mid-page, only the value when the page is completed will appear. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but this seems straightforward enough without being overly complex.